# How do I extract an Action into a member function?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have this code:

```
class SomeClass {
    void someFunction()
    {
          Action<string> myAction = (what)=>
          {
             //whatever
          }
          new List<string>().ForEach(myAction);
    }
}
```

I'd like to extract the code inside `myAction` into a separate member function.

How do I do that?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: why does `Action` vs `Func` make any difference?

Comment: @DanPuzey i thought the OP wants to get a `MemberExpression` not a member function ^^ ... just realized that it was about extracting a method ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be equivalent:

```
class SomeClass {

    void myAction(string what)
    {
        // whatever
    }

    void someFunction()
    {
          new List<string>().ForEach(item => myAction(item));
    }
}
```

Since `Action<string>` means `a method with a string parameter which does not return a value`.

Answer (score 7):

```
class SomeClass
{
    void someFunction()
    {
        Action<string> myAction = Whatever;
        new List<string>().ForEach(myAction);
    }

    public void Whatever(string what)
    {
        // ... whenever
    }
}
```

or directly, without defining a local `Action<string>` variable (that will probably be optimized away in Release mode anyway):

```
new List<string>().ForEach(Whatever);
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for this?

```
class SomeClass { 
    void someFunction() 
    { 
          new List<string>().ForEach(SeparateMemberFunction); 
    }
    void SeparateMemberFunction(string s)
    {
        //whatever
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a different way:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public void SomeFunction()
    {               
        new List<string>().ForEach(e => this.MyAction(e));
   }

    private void MyAction(string str){ /* ... */ }
}
```

I find it clearer because I see at first sight `MyAction`is a method and not a `field` or a  `property`